# how to use twitter error code responses in windows phone development

Tags: twitter, windows-phone-8

im using a twitter api to search for user names, however i want to do some error handling with the error code responses. This is the website im looking at for the code https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses

And I want to catch these possible erors. Im trying

```
  catch (Exception error)
        {

          //do thing


        }
```

But I cant seem to fill in the blanks. Can someone help me so that if the code 404, for example, happens then it will display the message for that error code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The handling depends on which HTTP library you're using. If it's WebClient or HttpWebRequest, you could catch a WebException and inspect the StatusCode property of the Response property. e.g.

```
((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode
```

If you're using HttpClient, which is my personal preference, you'll get an HttpResponseMessage back from a query like PostAsync or SendAsync. You can read the StatusCode from that HttpResponseMessage to know what Twitter responded with. Here's the LINQ to Twitter error handler (a work in-progress):

```
﻿using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LinqToTwitter.Common;
using LitJson;

namespace LinqToTwitter
{
    class TwitterErrorHandler
    {
        public static async Task ThrowIfErrorAsync(HttpResponseMessage msg)
        {
            // TODO: research proper handling of 304

            if ((int)msg.StatusCode < 400) return;

            switch (msg.StatusCode)
            {
                case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                    await HandleUnauthorizedAsync(msg);
                    break;
                default:
                    await HandleGenericErrorAsync(msg);
                    break;
            } 
        }

        internal static async Task HandleGenericErrorAsync(HttpResponseMessage msg)
        {
            string responseStr = await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            BuildAndThrowTwitterQueryException(responseStr, msg);
        }

        internal static void BuildAndThrowTwitterQueryException(string responseStr, HttpResponseMessage msg)
        {
            TwitterErrorDetails error = ParseTwitterErrorMessage(responseStr);

            throw new TwitterQueryException(error.Message)
            {
                ErrorCode = error.Code,
                StatusCode = msg.StatusCode,
                ReasonPhrase = msg.ReasonPhrase
            };
        }

        internal async static Task HandleUnauthorizedAsync(HttpResponseMessage msg)
        {
            string responseStr = await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            TwitterErrorDetails error = ParseTwitterErrorMessage(responseStr);

            string message = error.Message + " - Please visit the LINQ to Twitter FAQ (at the HelpLink) for help on resolving this error.";

            throw new TwitterQueryException(message)
            {
                HelpLink = "https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LINQ%20to%20Twitter%20FAQ",
                ErrorCode = error.Code,
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                ReasonPhrase = msg.ReasonPhrase
            };
        }

        internal static TwitterErrorDetails ParseTwitterErrorMessage(string responseStr)
        {
            if (responseStr.StartsWith("{"))
            {
                JsonData responseJson = JsonMapper.ToObject(responseStr);

                var errors = responseJson.GetValue<JsonData>("errors");

                if (errors != null)
                {
                    if (errors.GetJsonType() == JsonType.String)
                        return new TwitterErrorDetails
                        {
                            Message = responseJson.GetValue<string>("errors"),
                            Code = -1
                        };

                    if (errors.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var error = errors[0];
                        return new TwitterErrorDetails
                        {
                            Message = error.GetValue<string>("message"),
                            Code = error.GetValue<int>("code")
                        };
                    }
                }
            }

            return new TwitterErrorDetails { Message = responseStr };
        }

        internal class TwitterErrorDetails
        {
            public int Code { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```